When drawing the level 1 DFD
When I drawing the level 1 DFD, can I separate each of the interactions between each of the subsystem? For example, one subsystem's interaction between user and admin is in one figure, and another subsystem's interaction between user and admin is in another figure
It will show like this:

One subsystem connected with main system

Another subsystem connection with main system
It will display as two figure. Is it can if there's a lot of subsystem's interaction between studio member and admin. If can, how can i combine them in one figure only at last (if needed)?
Asking about context diagram level 1
